# How to validate credentials with CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials

Tags: c++, winapi, msdn

I don't know why I can't unpack the authentification buffer used in CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials with CredUnPackAuthenticationBufferW, I always get ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER error. 
I will appreciate your help.

```
std::wstring caption = L"Caption";
std::wstring msg= L"Msg";
CREDUI_INFOW credui = {};
credui.cbSize = sizeof(credui);
credui.hwndParent = nullptr;
credui.pszMessageText = msg.c_str();
credui.pszCaptionText = caption.c_str();
credui.hbmBanner = nullptr;

ULONG  authPackage = 0;
LPVOID outCredBuffer = nullptr;
ULONG  outCredSize = 0;
BOOL   save = false;

LPWSTR pszUserName = nullptr;
DWORD pcchlMaxUserName = 0;
LPWSTR pszDomainName = nullptr;
DWORD pcchMaxDomainName = 0;
LPWSTR pszPassword = nullptr;
DWORD pcchMaxPassword = 0;

DWORD result = CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW(&credui,
                                                0,
                                                &authPackage,
                                                nullptr,
                                                0,
                                                &outCredBuffer,
                                                &outCredSize,
                                                &save,
                                                CREDUIWIN_ENUMERATE_ADMINS);


std::cout <<CredUnPackAuthenticationBufferW(CRED_PACK_PROTECTED_CREDENTIALS
                                ,outCredBuffer
                                ,outCredSize
                                ,pszUserName
                                ,&pcchlMaxUserName
                                ,pszDomainName
                                ,&pcchMaxDomainName
                                ,pszPassword
                                ,&pcchMaxPassword) << std::endl;

std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl; // out put 122 == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER
```

Comment: of course you and must got `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` because you pass 0 size buffer. you need allocate some buffers for `pszUserName` , `pszPassword` and `pszDomainName`. if it was insufficient size - use returned values (`pcchlMaxUserName`, `pcchMaxDomainName`, `pcchMaxPassword` ) - for reallocate buffers and call api again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is typical winapi pattern - api must return some information in the memory buffer. but instead allocate buffer yourself - it obligate caller to allocate buffer. 
so caller must allocate buffer itself and pass it pointer and size to api.
api check buffer size - if it large enough fill information to buffer, otherwise return `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` (assume that no another errors) or sometime `ERROR_MORE_DATA`. which which concrete error reurned `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` or `ERROR_MORE_DATA` usual direct documented for api call. different between this 2 errors: `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` - mean no any info filled to buffer at all, when `ERROR_MORE_DATA` mean some data is returned, but incomplete.
and api return to user, via some out parameter, required buffer size in this case. frequently this is done via the same inout parameter - pointer to DWORD. in input specifies the size of user allocated buffer, in output - specifies the required size of buffer or size of returned data

frequently which buffer size is required - unknown at begin. so we need or call api with 0 size buffers(s) first, or allocate some, supposedly sufficient buffer size. if buffer will be insuffient - reallocate or extend it and call api again. for some api (like `CredUnPackAuthenticationBufferW`) the required output buffer does not change with time (if input parameters not changed), but usual output buffer size may change between calls - even second call with buffer size returned by first call can fail with buffer size error (because returned data may grow between calls). in this case need call api in `do/while(error == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER/ERROR_MORE_DATA)` loop. but even in case output buffer does not change with time we can better do this is loop with single api call inside, instead 2 api calls.

for concrete case code can look like

```
ULONG cred()
{
    CREDUI_INFO ci = { sizeof(ci) };
    BOOL bSave = FALSE;

    PVOID pvOutAuthBuffer;
    ULONG ulOutAuthBufferSize;
    ULONG ulAuthPackage = 0;
    ULONG dwError = CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials(
        &ci, NOERROR, &ulAuthPackage, 0, 0, 
        &pvOutAuthBuffer, &ulOutAuthBufferSize, 
        &bSave, CREDUIWIN_ENUMERATE_ADMINS );

    if (dwError == NOERROR)
    {
        ULONG cchUserName = 0;
        ULONG cchPassword = 0;
        ULONG cchDomain = 0;

        static volatile UCHAR guz = 0;

        PWSTR stack = (PWSTR)alloca(guz);
        PWSTR szUserName = 0, szPassword = 0, szDomainName = 0;

        ULONG cchNeed, cchAllocated = 0;

        do 
        {
            if (cchAllocated < (cchNeed = cchUserName + cchPassword + cchDomain))
            {
                szUserName = (PWSTR)alloca((cchNeed - cchAllocated) * sizeof(WCHAR));
                cchAllocated = (ULONG)(stack - szUserName);
                szPassword = szUserName + cchUserName;
                szDomainName = szPassword + cchPassword;
            }

            dwError = CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer(
                CRED_PACK_PROTECTED_CREDENTIALS, 
                pvOutAuthBuffer, ulOutAuthBufferSize, 
                szUserName, &cchUserName, 
                szDomainName, &cchDomain, 
                szPassword, &cchPassword)
                ? NOERROR : GetLastError();

            if (dwError == NOERROR)
            {
                DbgPrint("%S@%S %S\n", szDomainName, szUserName, szPassword);
                break;
            }

        } while (dwError == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);

        CoTaskMemFree(pvOutAuthBuffer);
    }

    return dwError;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the very good clarification @RbMm. Now I can get some data stored in the the buffers, but they are encrypted, and I don't know how could I check whether the entered password (pin code, finger print...) are valid ?

Comment: @perrahmaouy - nothing is encrypted. you got data exactly

Comment: How to logon smart card user creds to get a handle to a token that represents the specified user? 

I need to validate the credentials feed by the smartcard & verify it is an administrator & launch a process using the user token. Any help would be appreciated.

@RbMm

Comment: @ArjunNatarajan serialize your credetials to `PKERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON` - and CspData in form `KERB_SMARTCARD_CSP_INFO` and pass this to `LsaLogonUser` - if all is ok - you got token for user

Answer (score 1):

@RbMm - you're right! I tested it with LogonUser, and it works perfectly. Thanks.
And for a ready solution, I got this :

```
bool Authenticate_ADMIN_User(std::wstring caption, std::wstring msg, int maxReAsks = 0)
{
    CREDUI_INFOW credui   = {};
    credui.cbSize         = sizeof(credui);
    credui.hwndParent     = nullptr;
    credui.pszMessageText = msg.c_str();
    credui.pszCaptionText = caption.c_str();
    credui.hbmBanner      = nullptr;

    ULONG  authPackage   = 0,
           outCredSize   = 0;
    LPVOID outCredBuffer = nullptr;
    BOOL   save          = false;

    DWORD err   = 0;
    int   tries = 0;

    bool reAsk = false;

    do
    {
      tries++;

      if(CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW(&credui,
                                         err,
                                         &authPackage,
                                         nullptr,
                                         0,
                                         &outCredBuffer,
                                         &outCredSize,
                                         &save,
                                         CREDUIWIN_ENUMERATE_ADMINS)

              != ERROR_SUCCESS)
          return false;


      ULONG cchUserName = 0;
      ULONG cchPassword = 0;
      ULONG cchDomain   = 0;
      ULONG cchNeed, cchAllocated = 0;

      static volatile UCHAR guz = 0;

      PWSTR stack = (PWSTR)alloca(guz);
      PWSTR szUserName = nullptr, szPassword = nullptr, szDomainName = nullptr;

      BOOL ret;

      do{
          if (cchAllocated < (cchNeed = cchUserName + cchPassword + cchDomain))
          {
              szUserName = (PWSTR)alloca((cchNeed - cchAllocated) * sizeof(WCHAR));
              cchAllocated = (ULONG)(stack - szUserName);
              szPassword = szUserName + cchUserName;
              szDomainName = szPassword + cchPassword;
          }

          ret = CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer(
              CRED_PACK_PROTECTED_CREDENTIALS , outCredBuffer, outCredSize, szUserName, &cchUserName,
              szDomainName, &cchDomain, szPassword,
              &cchPassword);

      }while(!ret && GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);


        SecureZeroMemory(outCredBuffer, outCredSize);
        CoTaskMemFree(outCredBuffer);

        HANDLE handle = nullptr;

        if (LogonUser(szUserName, 
                      szDomainName,
                      szPassword,
                      LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, 
                      LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                      &handle)) 
        {

          CloseHandle(handle);
          return true;
        }

        else
        {
          err = ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE;
          reAsk = true;
        }


    }while(reAsk && tries < maxReAsks);

    return false;
}
```